# How to specify the output format of a powerpoint video export in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, powerpoint

To create a video from a powerpoint presentation I can use for example

```
ppFile.CreateVideo fileName, false, 1, 793, 2, 100
```

How can I define the format of the output file.
Obviously I can call the fileName foo.mp4 or foo.wav but I have my doubts that this really changes the way the video is encoded as apposed to just changing the suffix of the file.

What is the default encoding method and how can one select a different encoding method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [output is WMV](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerpoint-help/turn-your-presentation-into-a-video-HA010336763.aspx), if you want a different format you must convert using a transcoding utility, [for example the ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/73529/how-to-convert-wmv-to-mp4) command line tool.